# Remove node by ID in jstree when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using **jstree** and I want to delete a specific node by its ID after a click on a button.

This is my tree in html list format:

```
<div id="testtree">
    <ul>
        <li id="1" title="ID:1"><a>Fruits and Vegetables</a>
          <ul>
        <li id="11" title="ID:11"><a>Fruit</a>
              <ul>
                <li id="111" title="ID:111"><a>Apple</a></li>
                <li id="112" title="ID:112"><a>Banana</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my button event (I've got several buttons, hence the array):

```
buttons[0].addEventListener( "click", function( ev ) {
        $("#testtree").jstree("remove", $("111")); 
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

**Update:**

I've corrected the typo but it still doesn't work. Here's the complete code, maybe the mistake is somewhere else?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jstree test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testtree">
        <ul>
            <li id="1" title="ID:1"><a>Fruits and Vegetables</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="11" title="ID:11"><a>Fruit</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="111" title="ID:111"><a>Apple</a></li>
                            <li id="112" title="ID:112"><a>Banana</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <button>Remove Apple</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#testtree").jstree({
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "ui" ],
                "core": { "initially_open": ["1"]}
            });
        });

        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

        buttons[0].addEventListener( "click", function( ev ) {
            $("#testtree").jstree("remove","#111");
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In jQuery you can write: `$("#testtree #111").remove();`

Comment: That works, but I need to be able to reload the tree later on without missing nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to jsTree [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm) you remove like this

```
 $("#testtree").jstree("remove","#111");
```

Without `$()`

```
   $("#testtree").jstree({
       "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "ui", "crrm"],
       "core": {
           "initially_open": ["1"]
       }
   });
```

You need to add "crrm" to plugins

Comment: I've tried this, but it still doesnt work. I've updated my complete code in the first post, maybe the mistake is somewhere else?

Comment: Ok, going to test it out on my computer

Comment: I tried `$("#testtree").jstree("delete_node","#111");`and it worked. But it seems that "delete_node" removes the node permanently which is unfortunate when I want to reset the tree to its original state.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impressioned that "remove()" belongs to "core" and not to "crrm". Now I've only got the problem to reset the tree to its original state - should I open a new topic or can I bother you further?

Comment: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core check out this and look at .save_opend () and .refresh(node)

Answer (score 6):

Any of the answers worked for me. I prefer to use that instead:

```
$.jstree._reference("#tree-container or node or jquery selector").delete_node(node);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: plus one this is the one that did it for me thanks. no extra plugin needed.

Answer (score 6):

jsTree's [manual](http://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/) (ver 3.0.0) says:

> Please keep in mind that by default all modifications to the tree are
>   prevented (create, rename, move, delete). To enable them set
>   core.check_callback to true

You can also use function to specify the type of modification to allow. For example, to allow only node removing:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            // operation can be 'create_node', 'rename_node', 'delete_node', 'move_node' or 'copy_node'
            // in case of 'rename_node' node_position is filled with the new node name
            return operation === 'delete_node';
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me without using any external plugin.

```html
$('#treeid').jstree().delete_node([node.id]);
$('#treeid').jstree("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me very well.

I have more than 70,000 leaf nodes & this removes instantaneously.

```
this.getFilterTree().jstree("destroy");
this.getFilterTree().html("");


//return tree holder div
getFilterTree: function() {
return $('#jstreeHolder');
}
```

After removing you can instantiate tree once again !

Answer (score 0):

Add `check_callback = true;` inside core of jsTree config (eg. `core.check_callback = true;`) , then `$('#tree').jstree(true).delete_node(*yourNodeId*);`

fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/sqiudward/kf2eym0k/

Answer (score 0):

Currently "crrm" plugin is not active.

According to jsTree [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=delete_node(obj)) you can delete node.

For example;

```
var node = $("#tree").jstree(true).get_node("111");//111 is node id
$("#tree").jstree("delete_node", node);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a typo:
try:

```
$("#testtree").jstree("remove", $("#111"));
```