# Js tree : something wrong with my config?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I am doing something wrong in my jstree config but i can't find what.
It prevents me from deleting the nodes, when i use the default config to delete by example the node with id = 106, it works fine. So at least i know my html is correct.

This is the working default code

```
$('#jstree').jstree({ core : { check_callback : true } });

var t = $('#jstree').jstree(true);
t.select_node('106');
t.delete_node(['106']);
```

this is my config

```
$("#jstree").jstree({

  "core": {
    "animation": 0,
    "check-callback": true,
    "themes": {
      "icons": true,
      "stripes": true,
    }
  },
  // plugins
  "plugins": [
    "contextmenu", "types"
  ],
  "types": {
    "root": {
      "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"
    },
    "folder": {
      "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tags"
    },
    "tag": {
      "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tag"
    },
  },
  // modify the contextmenu content with customMenu() function
  "contextmenu": {
    "items": function($node) {

      return {
        "Create": {
          "separator_before": false,
          "separator_after": false,
          "label": "Create Folder",
          "action": function(obj) {
            this.node_create();
          }
        },
        "Rename": {
          "separator_before": false,
          "separator_after": false,
          "label": "Rename",
          "action": function(obj) {
            this.node_rename();
          }
        },
        "Remove": {
          "separator_before": false,
          "separator_after": false,
          "label": "Delete",
          "action": function(obj) {

            var t = $('#jstree').jstree(true);
            t.select_node('106');
            t.delete_node(['106']);

          }
        }
      };

    }
  }

});
```

I looked up the other answers but they did not help.
I found out what the problem was see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove node by ID in jstree when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376165/remove-node-by-id-in-jstree-when-button-is-clicked)

Comment: It does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error

I had to change

```
"check-callback": true,
```

to

```
"check_callback": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code have one error, maybe not solve the problem but can help something.
 See:

```
$("#jstree").jstree({

"core": {
"animation": 0,
"check-callback": true,
"themes": {
  "icons": true,
  "stripes": true,
}
},
// plugins
  "plugins": [
      contextmenu", "types"
   ],
  "types": {
       "root": {
           "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"
        },
        "folder": {
            "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tags"
        },
       "tag": {
          "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-tag"
       }, //This "," cannot display here, because is last of the group
   },
  ...
```

I hope help to solve your problem! :)

Comment: @Keutelvocht Sorry i can´t solve your issue, but good luck! :)